# Slow query Mysql with Order By and JOIN

Tags: mysql, performance, join, order-by, amazon-rds-aurora

I've been investigating an issue with a slow query when trying to get the last 50 comments of a user.
To give some context the database size is 9 TiB and the COMMENT table has about 7 billon of rows.
Sometimes the query takes 20 seconds to execute and as you can imagine that causes a lot of troubles.

### QUERY

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM comment t1 USE INDEX(post_comment_id_idx)
JOIN post_user t2 on t2.brand_id = t1.brand_id and t2.post_id = t1.post_id
WHERE t2.brand_id ='xxxxx' 
AND t2.user_type ='A'
AND t2.user_id ='123' 
ORDER BY t1.id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

### EXPLAIN

```
# id    select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  t1      ref post_comment_id_idx post_comment_id_idx 182 const   1   100.00  Using index condition; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  t2      ref brand_user_idx,brand_post_idx   brand_user_idx  546 const,const,const   1   100.00  Using index condition; Using where
```

My first guess is that the issue is in the `ORDER BY` because when I remove it, the query takes ms.

Another approach I took is split the query in two like this: and it also shows an improvement in the performance.

#### WORKAROUND

```
SET @postIds := (
SELECT t2.post_id 
FROM post_user t2
WHERE t2.brand_id ='xxxxx' and t2.user_type ='A'
AND t2.user_id ='67456380001'
                            );
                            
SELECT t1.*
FROM comment t1 USE INDEX(post_comment_id_idx)
WHERE t1.brand_id ='xxxxx'
AND t1.post_id in (@postIds)
order by t1.id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

But I would expect that the Database takes care of this optimization instead of having to split the query manually. It sounds more like a hack, and I think there should be a better way to access to these results with a single query.

## QUESTION

Is there way I could improve this query?
I need to find a solution and I would like to let the workaround as my last option.

MySQL Version: 5.7.12-log

#### STRUCTURE

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `brand_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`brand_id`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
;

CREATE TABLE `post_user` (
  `id` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `brand_user_idx` (`brand_id`,`user_type`,`user_id`),
  KEY `brand_post_idx` (`brand_id`,`post_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `brand_post_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`, `post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`brand_id`, `id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
;

CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `id` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  `brand_comment_log_seq` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_comment_log_seq` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_flags` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_json` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `comment_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `comment_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inserted_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `issue_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `private` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `brand_post_time_seq_uk` (`brand_id`,`post_id`,`comment_time`,`brand_comment_log_seq`),
  KEY `post_issue_idx` (`brand_id`,`post_id`,`issue_id`),
  KEY `post_comment_id_idx` (`brand_id`,`post_id`,`id`),
  KEY `brand_comment_id_idx` (`brand_id`,`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `_FKbrand-postid` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`, `post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`brand_id`, `id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
;
```

## EDIT

### EXPLAIN without USE INDEX(post_comment_id_idx)

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, t1, , ref, brand_post_time_seq_uk,post_issue_idx,post_comment_id_idx,brand_comment_id_idx, brand_post_time_seq_uk, 182, const, 1, 100.00, Using index condition; Using filesort
1, SIMPLE, t2, , ref, brand_user_idx,brand_post_idx, brand_user_idx, 546, const,const,const, 1, 100.00, Using index condition; Using where
```

Please, let me know if more information is needed.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me post the result here.
```
# id select_type table partitions type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
1 SIMPLE t1  ref brand_post_time_seq_uk,post_issue_idx,post_comment_id_idx,brand_comment_id_idx brand_post_time_seq_uk 182 const 1 100.00 Using index condition; Using filesort
1 SIMPLE t2  ref brand_user_idx,brand_post_idx brand_user_idx 546 const,const,const 1 100.00 Using index condition; Using where
```
It's different. but it's still using filesort

Comment: Now - why are most of the ID columns varchar? are they not numeric? And why are you telling it to use `post_comment_id_idx` ?

Comment: Most of the ID columns are generated at the App level, for example for the COMMENT.ID we use ULID, that's why we decided to sort by ID.
Regarding `post_comment_id_idx` I'm not sure why it was done that way. I assume becuse that INDEX contains the 3 main fields we are using in the query `brand_id`,`post_id`,`id`

Answer (score 2):

Add these composite indexes:

```
t2 (post_user):  INDEX(brand_id, user_type, user_id,  post_id) -- replacing brand_user_idx
t1 (comment):  INDEX(brand_id, post_id, id)
```

(and remove the `USE INDEX`)

The problem is that it must gather all the possible rows based on the `WHERE` and `ON`, then sort them, and finally peel off 50.  There is no shortcut to get avoid the sort and get to the limit.

Shouldn't you be ordering by `comment_time` instead of `id`?

`SET @ids := ( SELECT ... )` cannot handle an array, only a single value.

There is *some* hope.  The `SELECT *` needs to be done for all those rows around awaiting the order by and limit.  (This may explain why the query occasionally takes longer.)  Let's cut it back to a max of 50.

```
SELECT  t3.*
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  c1.id
            FROM  post_user pu
            JOIN  comment c1
               ON  pu.brand_id = c1.brand_id
              AND  pu.post_id = c1.post_id
            WHERE  pu.brand_id ='xxxxx'
              AND  pu.user_type ='A'
              AND  pu.user_id ='123'
            ORDER BY  c1.id DESC
            LIMIT  50 
        ) AS ids
    JOIN  comment AS c3  ON c3.id = ids.id
    ORDER BY  t3.comment_time DESC
```

This way, 50 ids are fetched from an index-only ("covering" or "Using index") query, then it reaches into `comment` again to get the rest of the columns, a max of 50 times.